# Language school & language institute

Tags: word-choice

I'm a non-native English speaker in Iran. Here we have schools to which students go to learn about different subjects such as math, history and English. We have institutes (or at least we call them that) that students of different ages go to learn a foreign language. I googled language school and got the same definition that suits institutes in Iran! I became confused and curious: is language school something we don't have in Iran or do we use the wrong word to describe it here? the word usually goes on top of the building in which they teach foreign languages!!

what's the difference between a language school & a language institute? Which one is OK to use in the context I just mentioned above? Maybe both?!

Comment: What does your dictionary say about the difference between "school" and "institute?'

Comment: Well I'm a non-native English speaker in Iran. Here we have schools in which students go and learn about different subjects like math, history, etc and English included. We have institutes (or atleast we call them that) that students of different ages go and learn a foreign language. I googled language school and got the same definition that suits institutes in Iran! I became confused and curious if language school somethibg we don't have in Iran or they use the wrong word to discribe it here!!

Comment: It's probably too strong to suggest they are using the wrong word; it is more likely that there is a subtle difference between the two types of establishment which can be expressed in Farsi but not in English.

Comment: I see. Actually I kind of got panic-attacked to have this idea that this possible mistake is so prevalent among language learners here! The reason is that by institute I get the impression of a systematic organization that does scientific research or something not including practitioners like teachers dealing with learners. Language school dfinition that I came across in wikipedia testifies on this.

Comment: I'd relax - there may be a real answer out there, but it sounds to me like this is just part of an English dialect in Iraq (and possibly other parts of Asia). Each culture English comes in contact with influences the type of English spoken there.

Comment: Ok, then I'm gonna take your advice and lie back ☺ Thank you guys for your comments.

Comment: In the US an "institute" may be a highfalutin, highly respected research organization which operates off a $10 billion endowment, or it may be a low budget "school" operating out of a hotel room.  It's just a name, and pretty much any organization can call itself an "institute".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on ELL but is too old to migrate.